# Cannot connect to the Internet using a Realtek Lan RTL8105TA card

Tags: ethernet, elementary-os, lan

I have made a LiveUsb to Elementary before installing it on my notebook. Everything works fine except for the internet. I don't have WiFi, but a wired connection. I cannot connect to the internet in any way. My Ethernet card is a Realtek Lan RTL8105TA.

```
elementary@elementary:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:7d:7b:9f:8a:72  
          inet addr:10.118.14.86  Bcast:10.118.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::67d:7bff:fe9f:8a72/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21692 errors:0 dropped:8 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:935 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1809988 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:97546 (97.5 KB)
          Interrupt:44 Base address:0xe000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:84217 (84.2 KB)  TX bytes:84217 (84.2 KB)

elementary@elementary:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

elementary@elementary:~$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

elementary@elementary:~$ lspci -k | grep -A2i net ; nmcli d list
grep: 2i: invalid context length argument
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           802-11-wireless
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Atheros Communications Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath9k
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:ED:B9:79:C6:99
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     not connected
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           802-3-ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         04:7D:7B:9F:8A:72
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 10.118.14.86/16, gw = 10.118.0.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.16.172.9
IP4.DNS[2]:                             172.16.172.10
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        expiry = 1416959395
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        broadcast_address = 10.118.255.255
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        routers = 10.118.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 2592000
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        ip_address = 10.118.14.86
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        domain_name_servers = 172.16.172.9 172.16.172.10
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        ntp_servers = 192.43.244.18
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       network_number = 10.118.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.3.1
```

Comment: Since elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, you might want to look up "how to switch on network on Ubuntu" - that could give you some clues about how to fix the problem at least temporarily.

Comment: Whould you so kind to supplyus with more info? For example `lspci -k | grep -A2i net ; nmcli d list`

Comment: @Costas I have the info you wanted. Please help!

Comment: @MinhazMahmood Say again what do the problem is? As I can see from your data all devices (lan and wlan) are recognized by the OS and ready to work. Lan is connected, configured and, hope to, work. WiFi do not connected but it isn't for trouble reason. What do `rfkill list` shows?